# tr:hover won't trigger on invisible td

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, visibility

I want to make a table in which hovering over a row makes some buttons appear for that row.  Right now, I have the buttons (actually just text) always there, and when a table row is hovered over, I change the visibility on the buttons from hidden to visible.  However, the hover event does not seem to trigger on a hidden td element, even though the event is actually on the tr.  How can I fix this?  I don't want to just set the opacity to 0 because then they still can be clicked on (right?).  Eventually I want to be able to turn on and off the hover effect by adding/removing a class, so that is why the opacity doesn't work.

My code looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h7oh9xvk/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td class='precell'>X</td><td>blablabla</td><td class='postcell'>[edit]</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='precell'>X</td><td>blablabla</td><td class='postcell'>[edit]</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='precell'>X</td><td>blablabla</td><td class='postcell'>[edit]</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.precell, .postcell {
    visibility: hidden;
}
tr:hover .precell {
    visibility:visible;
}
tr:hover .postcell {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Edit: Additional Information: One of the main problems seems to be that the space between td elements in a row does not seem to count as part of the row (does not trigger the hover event on the row).  When I move the mouse horizontally from one cell to another, it seems there is a space between td's where the hover "shuts off."  Is there a way to stop this?  That might fix the problem.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/h7oh9xvk/2/

Comment: `I don't want to just set the opacity to 0 because then they still can be clicked on (right?).` That's kind of exactly why this doesn't work. Either you have an element that generates mouse events or you don't. You can't pick and chose which mouse events (hover) it generates and which it won't (click). You could add a click handler that just does nothing if the `td` has `opacity` of 0.

Comment: @MattBurland but if they are able to click that means they are within the scope of the row and are hovering, in which case you want the `td`'s to appear and able to receive a click.

Comment: @Brian: I was actually about to make the same point. Which makes the OP's complaint that they can still be clicked totally moot.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. If I'm going to click the td, I'll be hovering it. And your request is that hovering the side tds trigger the hover of the whole tr. So, what difference does it make if it's clickable or not?

Comment: Eventually I will want to put this in a class that I can turn on and off (so depending on the situation the buttons will appear or not when I hover), and change what happens when I hover.  I want the hover event to be fired whenever I am on the row, no matter if the tds are visible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is simply impossible to trigger a hover event in the way I wanted, but it turns out there is an easy solution.  If we include a div within the td, and act on that instead, it works perfectly:

```css
.precell, .postcell {
  visibility: hidden;
}
tr:hover .precell {
  visibility:visible;
}
tr:hover .postcell {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td> <div class='precell'>X</div></td><td>blablabla</td><td> <div class='postcell'>[edit]</div></td></tr>
  <tr><td> <div class='precell'>X</div></td><td>blablabla</td><td> <div class='postcell'>[edit]</div></td></tr>
  <tr><td> <div class='precell'>X</div></td><td>blablabla</td><td> <div class='postcell'>[edit]</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: none` / `display: table-cell`:

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.precell, .postcell {
    display: none;
    width:0px;
}
tr:hover .precell {
    display: table-cell;
}
td {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
tr:hover .postcell {
    display: table-cell;
}
tr, td {padding:0px;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='precell'>X</td>
        <td style="margin-left:15px;">blablabla</td>
        <td class='postcell'>[edit]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='precell'>X</td>
        <td style="margin-left:15px;">blablabla</td>
        <td class='postcell'>[edit]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='precell'>X</td>
        <td style="margin-left:15px;">blablabla</td>
        <td class='postcell'>[edit]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Updated after @Mary Melody comment.

Comment: I think this is exactly what the OP was wanting. Beat me to it.

Comment: I like this, but is there a way to keep the spacing (so the content is not jumping around every time I hover)?

Comment: Really try to figure out why there is space and i can't!

Comment: `display: none;` will cause it to jump in general because the element does not occupy space until its hovered, but the extra space over and above that it iss causing is a bit unexpected

Comment: the strange part is if i used e.g. `position: absolute` in td the space is still there!!

Comment: inherit it's original state with `display: inherit;` instead of `display: table-cell;` and it works, still jumps because of `display: none;` but does't have the abnormal behavior anymore

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Brian but looks even more strange:P

Comment: only the first time you hover, lol afterwards it behaves.. how strange http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/h7oh9xvk/12/

Comment: Yes, but is still strange even the first time :)

Comment: Very nice indeed @MaryMelody. Can i use it to update my answer?

Comment: @MaryMelody i think is ok now. I change a bit your code too :)

Comment: @AlexChar I think, this is perfect. try this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/kvtwqvvL/5/

Comment: Nice fix, from the question: "the hover event does not seem to trigger on a hidden td element." Because the default state is `display: none;` you can't hover the `td` and have it display due to not maintaining a hover-able width

Comment: @AlexChar +0001) I think, I didn't understand the question. lol :)

Comment: This is pretty good, but still has the problem that when I hover over one of the hidden elements, it does not appear.  It seems like it should, since even though the hover event on the td doesn't fire, the mouse is still over part of the row.